# Java: connect 4, bad operand types for binary operator error

Tags: java, arrays, operator-keyword

I'm getting some weird bad operand errors which I cannot seem to resolve.

```
public class Model {

// Keep track of whether a move animation is currently playing.
// When a move animation is busy then no new moves are allowed.
private boolean moveInProgress = false;
private int[][] pieces = new int[7][7];
private boolean gameOver = false;


public void checkGameOver() {
    // TODO (step 3): implement this correctly.
    gameOver = true;
}

/**
 * Check if a new disk can be inserted in the current column.
 * @param column
 * @return true if and only if a move in this column is allowed.
 */
public boolean playableMove(int column) {
    // No new moves are allowed when an animation is busy.
    if (getMoveInProgress()) {
        return false;
    }
    // TODO (step 3) No moves are allowed when the game is over.
    if (gameOver) {
        return false;
    }
    // TODO: Check if this move is playable.
    if (pieces[column] > 6) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

/**
 * Compute the final destination row of a candidate move.
 * @param column
 * @return the row.
 */
public int moveDestination(int column) {
    // TODO: implement this method properly.
    int positie = 6 - pieces[column];
    return positie;
}

/**
 * Commit the insertion of a new disk in a given column.
 * @param column
 */
public void playMove(int column) {
    // TODO: Verify the following preconditions:
    // assert (isGameOver() == false);
    // assert (playableMove(column) == true);

    // TODO: Update the model to reflect the new move.

    // TODO (step 3): Also check for termination conditions.

    // TODO (step 3): Notify subscribers about important model changes.

    if (!gameOver && playableMove(column)) {

        pieces[column]++;
    }
}
}
```

The errors are at

(76,28) bad operator for binary operator '>'
first type int[]
second type int

The same error is repeated 4 times.

Can anyone help me with this

Comment: What in the error message don't you understand? You're trying to check if `pieces[column] > 6`, but `pieces[column]` is an array (since `pieces` is a 2D array) and it doesn't make sense to ask whether an array is greater than 6.

Comment: Thank you for your input, I just plainly suck with arrays, any ideas to resolve the issue using .lenght didnt work completely.

Answer (score 0):

You've defined `private int[][] pieces = new int[7][7];`. So when you access it with `pieces[column]`, you're left with an array, so you can't compare it with an `int`.

You probably meant `pieces[column].length` ?

Comment: I originally made this program to work with a 1d array, but later on I had to use a 2d one, and since I suck at arrays, I couldn't resolve it. Anyways thanks for the suggestion I'll try it out.

Comment: It worked except for the pieces[column]++ any suggestions there?

Comment: Again, `pieces[column]` is an **array**. You can not add 1 to an array.

Comment: @Eludum What do you think `pieces[column]++` means?

Comment: @glglgl Add + 1 to a column but that isn't an int so it won't work, only thing is I need to add +1 to the column but don't know how to do that in a 2d array.

Comment: Why do you use a 2D array in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do any arithmetic operations with each element of an array, you'll have to do so explicitly.

For example,

```
if (!gameOver && playableMove(column)) {
    for (int i=0; i < pieces[column].length; i++) {
        pieces[column][i]++;
    }
}
```

About the other checks (`6 - pieces[column]` which is meant to result in an integer and `pieces[column] > 6` which leaves it unclear if this condition is meant to be applied to all elements or at least one) I cannot help you due to unknown preconditions.